# Angular 5 - angular adds localhost:4200 infront of URL in style

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Hi i'm new to angular and not able to solve the problem.
I'm getting a image-url from server which is `localhost:8080` but when I try to set URL as a `background-image`, its not working.
In app.component.html:

```
<div class="card" [style.background-image]="tempImg">
</div>
```

In component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  tempImg = "http://localhost:8080/image/X_X_X_BG.png";
}
```

When I run this code in console getting error :
http://localhost:4200/localhost:8080/image/X_X_X_BG.png - 404 not found.

How to neglect the first localhost:4200??

Comment: I guess you can change the port which angular uses to 8080 and set your URL to /image/X_X_X_BG.png

Comment: But If it's coming from another server...example from eclipse...so both can't be run in same port.

Comment: Could it be, perhaps, because you are missing a slash in tempImg?
Also, you could try to wrap your background-image in url(tempImage)

Comment: Great bro...That missing slash resolved my problem...

Comment: I could post an answer if you want, @Vinay Sharma.

Comment: no thanks I resolved that....Thanks for ur support

Comment: Where was the missing slash ? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: Check my edit history. I missed one slash after http://